# Payment method markup in transactional email

Tags: transactional

I need custom markup for payment method details in new order email.

There seems to be only a single variable available for payment method markup `{{var payment_html}}`

Wondering what's the best way to do it?

Is there a way to add custom variables in transactional email so that I can create custom ones like `{{var payment_cc_type}}` & `{{var payment_cc_last4}}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to rewrite `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer` and you'll have to create a concrete method for the magic method `setTemplateParams`:

```
public function setTemplateParams($params)
{

    //you'll have to load your custom block and template - try it this way:
    $block = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getLayout()->getBlock('custom/block');
    $block->setTemplate('custom/template.phtml');
    $html = $block->toHtml();

    $params['your_varname'] = $html;

    parent::setTemplateParams($params);

}
```

It's pretty simple - we're getting in between the magic method with a concrete method, injecting our template `{{var your_varname}}` handle for the email and then passing that up to the magic method!

Best of luck!